# Connecting 2 different models to get user data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller, associations

i'm trying to figure out the proper way to do this, but if i have 2 models, how do I get the data from the 1st Model in the 2nd MVC. Example:

Model 1: User

Model 2: Post

I have a "user_id" field in the Post Model. If I am in the Post Controller/View, how do I fetch the user's first and last name from Model 1?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Google: rails associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `user` association in the Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

Then it is as easy as:

```
post.user.first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up associations - With Active Record associations, we can streamline these - and other - operations by declaratively telling Rails that there is a **connection between the two models**.-- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```